# How to predict with the known information in an undirected graph

Tags: graph, machine-learning, bioinformatics

Protein-protein interaction networks are known. It is an undirected graph. Each row of the networks is like this (Protein 2 - Protein 6), and It represents the interaction between Protein 2 and Protein 6.

```
networks:
Protein 2 - Protein 6
Protein 4 - Protein 5
Protein 6 - Protein 5
Protein 5 - Protein 7
...
```

In this network, the function of some proteins are known, and proteins with similar function tend to be relevant.

```
The function of some proteins:
Protein 2,Func_002
Protein 2,Func_007
Protein 2,Func_008
Protein 3,Func_007
Protein 3,Func_008
Protein 3,Func_009
Protein 4,Func_011
Protein 5,Func_015
...
```

And It is known that a part of proteins are cancer-related proteins.

```
The known proteins:
Protein 4,Cancer
Protein 6, Cancer
Protein 7, Cancer
Protein 10, Cancer
...
```

But the vast majority of proteins is unknown whether is cancer-related protein or noncancer-related protein. How can you use the known cancer-related proteins to predict the protein whether is or not a cancer-related protein?

I do not know how to solve this problem.

Comment: This question is very interesting but I'm voting to close it as it is very broad to answer here, it's also not related to programming.

Comment: you should look at the question here related to Machine Learning. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130524/which-stack-exchange-website-for-machine-learning-and-computational-algorithms

Comment: seems like your best bet is to get over to http://stats.stackexchange.com/ it has >4000 machine-learning related questions

Comment: each protein has a one to many relationship. then this is a graph. you want a probability as to whether a certain protein is cancerous or not. so you look at the graph and label each known protein. they might cluster (1) - so my only bet as a machine-learning newbie is that you need to use ML categorization. it's a binary option : is it, or is it not cancerous ?. look at scikit http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/classification/plot_classifier_comparison.html.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the **PageRank** algorithm.

E.g. initialize cancer with +1, nonCancer with -1, and then perform power iterations until change is smaller than a threshold 1e-10.
Those with positive weight are more related to the cancer proteins.

Comment: Protein-Protein Interaction networks is an undirected graph. can  PageRank do it?

Comment: Replace every undirected edge with two edges going both ways. Yes, PageRank can work with that.